# Word: VBA Bookmark highlight unremovable

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a couple of Bookmarks in a template that I was provided. These Bookmarks are highlighted grey and I can't remove this highlight/shadow.

What I have tried so far is:

```
ActiveDocument.FormFields(strBookmark).Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
ActiveDocument.FormFields(strBookmark)..Highlight = False
```

and some other things (search results also at StackOverflow).

Only applying another highlight can cover it up. I can't find the function within Word which controls highlighting of bookmarks.

Unfortunately, there is a part in that template that has a grey background. Hence, a white highlighted TextBox does not really look awesome.

I hope there is someone who is familiar with this bookmark issue and can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are describing is how shaded fields (with bookmarks) look in Word. You cannot really change their appearance other than to turn on or off field shading and view or not view bookmarks. This is an attribute set up in Word options and presumably a setting saved per user. You get to these options by File/Options/Advanced/Show Document Content/

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution StevenMpls, however, it did not solve my problem. Bookmarks stay highlighted. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I found the setting for my issue. Apparently, additionally to all the different described highlighting functions for formfields there is another. It is accessible via the Developers tab on the ribbon and is placed within the controls section. By clicking the "legacy tools" icon one can activate/deactive the FormField shading.

Comment: Good to hear, makes sense now that you mention it.